# Vb.net Webbrowser dropdown value changes but event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I am working on a way to navigate a webpage through code.  If you manually navigate to the page if you pick an option from the dropdown the page changes based on the option chosen.

When trying in code I can get the value to change according to what I want, however the page doesn't automatically change afterwards.  I want to be able to invoke the onsubmit to get the page to change based on the option selected.

I have tried

```
Dim option As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Account")
option.SetAttribute("value", "1")
option.SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

Along with various combinations of RaiseEvent and InvokeMember with "onChange", "click", "submit", "onSubmit", etc on the form, input, and select

```
<div id="ContainerContentSectionInvestment">
<form action="javascript:void(0);" id="StatementssFilterForm" onsubmit="updateView(&#39;StatementsContainer&#39;,&#39;/Secure/Statements/StatementByAccountAndDate&#39;, this);">
<input type="submit" id="StatementsFilterSubmit" class="chaseutil-hide" />
    <span class="chaseutil-black chaseutil-marginleft-10">
        <Label For="Account">Account </Label>
        <Select id="Account" class="chasejs-submitsform chaseanalytics-track-option" name="Account">
            <Option Value="1" Selected="Selected">Option 1</Option>
            <Option Value="2">Option 2</Option>
            <Option Value="3">Option 3</Option>
            <Option Value="4">Option 4</Option>
            <Option Value="5">Option 5</Option>
        </Select>
    </span>
```

How can I programatically get the event to trigger?

The following is the UpdateView function

```
var updateView = function(a) {
return function(b, c, d, e, f, g) {
    var h = a(".chasejs-isexpanded");
    if (h.length) {
        h.removeClass("chasejs-isexpanded")
    }
    var i, j, k = a(d),
        l = false;
    if (b.jquery) {
        i = b;
        j = i.attr("id")
    } else {
        if (b.tagName) {
            i = a(b);
            j = i.attr("id")
        } else {
            i = a("#" + b);
            j = b
        }
    }
    l = i.hasClass("chasejs-show-overlayspinner");
    if (d && (optionSelectedIsIgnored(d) || optionSelectedIsFlyout(d) || optionSelectedIsModal(d) || optionSelectedIsInstructionText(d) || optionSelectedIsFlyoutNav(d))) {
        return
    }
    if (e && i.is(".chasejs-hasbeenupdated")) {
        return false
    }
    if (d && k.is(".chasejs-flyoutlink")) {
        if (k.not(".chasejs-triggeredupdateview").length) {
            k.click(function() {
                if (k.not(".chasejs-triggeredupdateview").length) {
                    k.addClass("chasejs-triggeredupdateview");
                    updateView(b, c, d, e, f)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    var m = "GET";
    var n;
    var o = function(a) {
        updateViewCallback(i, a, d, j, g);
        i.trigger("updateViewCompleted")
    };
    var p = getViewportHeight();
    var q = displaySpinnerDiv(i, l);
    var r = displayDefaultError(i);
    if (c.indexOf("PropertiesList") > -1) r = '<div class="chaseui-ajaxloader" style="height:' + p + 'px;"><div class="chaseui-ajaxloadererror"><strong>We\'re unable to process your request.</strong> Our system is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for any inconvenience. Please try again later. </div></div>';
    var s = function() {
        i.fastempty().append(r)
    };
    if (f) {
        var t = new Object;
        a.each(f, function(b, c) {
            var d = a("#" + c);
            var e = d.attr("name");
            if (!e) {
                e = c
            }
            var f = d.attr("type");
            var g;
            if (f == "checkbox" || f == "radio") {
                g = d.prop("checked")
            } else {
                g = d.attr("value")
            }
            t[e] = g
        });
        c = appendQueryParameters(c, t)
    }
    if (k.is("form")) {
        formHandler(k);
        k.find(".chasejs-cleardefault").each(function() {
            removeDefaultValue(this)
        });
        n = k.serialize();
        k.find(".chasejs-cleardefault").each(function() {
            restoreDefaultValue(this)
        });
        m = "POST";
        try {
            a(window).attr("postedform", d)
        } catch (u) {}
    }
    if (i.is("#chasejs-contexthelpfloater")) {
        i.find(".chaseui-contexthelpcontentbody").fastempty().append(q)
    } else if (isDesignFamily.BP()) {
        q = '<div class="chaseui-ajaxloader" style="height:' + i.height() + 'px; top:15px;"><img alt="Please wait" src="' + RESOURCES_ROOT + '/images/loading.gif"></div>';
        i.fastempty().append(q);
        a(".chaseui-modalheader").css("border", "none")
    } else if (i.is(".chaseutil-suppress-spinner")) {
        i.fastempty()
    } else if (k.is(".chaseui-eip-buttonsubmit") && i.is(".chaseui-summaryblock")) {
        var v = a(".chaseui-eip-innercontainer").parent(".chaseui-eip-outercontainer").find("form");
        v.find(".chasejs-cleardefault").each(function() {
            removeDefaultValue(this)
        });
        DisableEditInPlaceCloseButton(true);
        n = v.serialize();
        m = v.attr("method");
        a(".chaseui-eip-innercontainer").fastempty().append(q)
    } else if (l) {
        i.append(q)
    } else {
        i.contents().hide().end().append(q)
    }
    if (isDesignFamily.Mol()) {
        a("div.chaseui-ajaxloader > img").addClass("chaseui-ajaxloader_new")
    } else {
        if (a("div.chaseui-ajaxloader").height() > p) {
            a("div.chaseui-ajaxloader > img").addClass("chaseui-ajaxloader_new")
        }
    }
    if (k.is("not:(.chasejs-flyoutlink)")) {
        a("#chasejs-contexthelpfloater").remove()
        }
        i.addClass("chasejs-hasbeenupdated");
        chasejax({
            url: c,
            type: m,
            dataType: null,
            data: n,
            $errorContainer: i,
            success: o,
            error: s
        })
    }
}(nisijQuery);
```

Comment: Can you include the updateView code?

Comment: I added the updateView code above.

Comment: Do you set any values in an onload() function for this page?  If you set the values in our updateView() function, but they're also set in onload() (without checking for ispostback, then onload() will overwrite whatever you set them to.

Comment: There is no onload function on the page

Comment: You can handle the onchange event in JavaScript. See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5pmkk8u0/

Comment: The application that does the logging in and processing is in VB already, this is the only piece I have left to figure out.  I know I can do this WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("updateView", New Object() {"'StatementsContainer'", "'/Secure/Statements/StatementByAccountAndDate'", this}) but I'm not sure what to actually pass in, instead of this.